# Link separate vega charts together?

Tags: vega-lite

Is it possible to link multiple vega charts on a web page without making them into one combined chart?

I'm trying to do this in a dashboard to allow me more control of styling, particularly by putting the graphs on different tiles and making those responsive. As per the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#specifying-responsive-width-and-height), combined charts **cannot** be made responsive with `"width": "container"`.

I created the following two example charts and embedded them into one HTML file, but I'm getting the following exception: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find a selection named "selector002".`

Is there any way to make this work with Vega? Alternatively, I'd be happy with a `vconcat` chart if I can somehow get it to adjust to the size of its parent container.

```json
{
    "config": {
        "view": {
            "continuousWidth": 400,
            "continuousHeight": 300
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "name": "data-07d1121d4bb402da807ced7f89269752"
    },
    "mark": "point",
    "encoding": {
        "x": {
            "type": "quantitative",
            "field": "A"
        },
        "y": {
            "type": "quantitative",
            "field": "B"
        }
    },
    "selection": {
        "selector002": {
            "type": "interval",
            "encodings": [
                "x"
            ]
        }
    },
    "width": "container",
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json",
    "datasets": {
        "data-07d1121d4bb402da807ced7f89269752": [
            {
                "A": 0.1,
                "B": 0.5,
                "C": 1.0
            },
            {
                "A": 0.1,
                "B": 0.8,
                "C": 0.0
            },
            {
                "A": 0.0,
                "B": 1.0,
                "C": 1.0
            },
            {
                "A": 0.2,
                "B": 0.8,
                "C": 1.0
            },
            {
                "A": 0.2,
                "B": 0.9,
                "C": 0.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "config": {
        "view": {
            "continuousWidth": 400,
            "continuousHeight": 300
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "name": "data-07d1121d4bb402da807ced7f89269752"
    },
    "mark": "bar",
    "encoding": {
        "color": {
            "type": "ordinal",
            "field": "B"
        },
        "x": {
            "type": "quantitative",
            "field": "A"
        },
        "y": {
            "type": "ordinal",
            "field": "C"
        }
    },
    "transform": [
        {
            "filter": {
                "selection": "selector002"
            }
        }
    ],
    "width": "container",
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json",
    "datasets": {
        "data-07d1121d4bb402da807ced7f89269752": [
            {
                "A": 0.1,
                "B": 0.5,
                "C": 1.0
            },
            {
                "A": 0.1,
                "B": 0.8,
                "C": 0.0
            },
            {
                "A": 0.0,
                "B": 1.0,
                "C": 1.0
            },
            {
                "A": 0.2,
                "B": 0.8,
                "C": 1.0
            },
            {
                "A": 0.2,
                "B": 0.9,
                "C": 0.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue related to this: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1830

[My latest reply on this issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1830#issuecomment-780175884) can help you:

> Here's a hack using the current version of VegaLite (`vega@5.17.0`, `vega-lite@4.17.0`, `vega-embed@6.12.2`), assuming that you have a `brush` selection in `vegalite_spec_for_minimap`:
>
> ```js
> vegaEmbed(`#minimap`, vegalite_spec_for_minimap)
>     .then(function(minimapVe){
>         minimapVe.view.addSignalListener('brush', function(signalName, e) {
>             console.log("updated");
>         });
>      });
> ```

Here is a full example:

```
timestampBounds = [1610580331317, 1610845273208];
chart_data.data.name = 'datatable';
vegaEmbed(`#main-chart`, chart_data).then(function(mainChartVe){
    // create a copy of data for the mini-map
    var minimap_data = $.extend(true, {}, chart_data);

    // set the height for minimap
    minimap_data.height = '50';

    // if you have an initial selection, apply it on the minimap
    if(timestampBounds) {
        minimap_data.selection = {"brush": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"], "init": {"x": timestampBounds}}};
    } else {
        minimap_data.selection = {"brush": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"]}};
    }

    function updateChartDataBasedOnSelection(timestampArr) {
        var filteredValues = minimap_data.data.values.filter(x => x.timestamp >= timestampArr[0] && x.timestamp <= timestampArr[1]);
        var changeset = vega.changeset().remove(vega.truthy).insert(filteredValues);
        mainChartVe.view.change('datatable', changeset).run();
    }

    // Have an initial selection
    if(timestampBounds) updateChartDataBasedOnSelection(timestampBounds);

    vegaEmbed(`#minimap`, minimap_data)
        .then(function(minimapVe){
            minimapVe.view.addSignalListener('brush', function(signalName, e) {
                if(e && e.timestamp) {
                    // update the main chart based on the selected data
                    updateChartDataBasedOnSelection(e.timestamp);
                }
            });
        });
});
```